# Error w/ Leaflet non-standard screen resolution

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am not sure what the problem is, but this is a description of behavior and description of the problem:

1. I have two points and a track (*it's all good now*):
   [image]
2. Change a scale of display (*to simulate the behavior of the laptop with non-standard resolution*)
   [image]
3. Now it's problem time:
   [image]

[image]

3.1. Both points remain in place, but the track moved out, and each time shifting it in any direction it will move.

I still use Leaflet **v0.7.3**

Anyone know what's the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the map with a zoom in an zoom out ?

Comment: Yes, I did, but no improvements.

Comment: This video shows error: https://youtu.be/_H8wzzaCfss

Comment: Well, I have to admit this is really weird. If a refresh of the map doesn't solve it I think that the problem may come from your code. Is it the same with another simple line ? Sometimes it's great to test it on a simple scenario with no extra features which may cause this problem.

Comment: The problem is that the track (path) is not on the zoom layer as markers. As the map. The research is ongoing.